# How do I read a integer from a file? Python help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am newish to python and I have a school project to be coded in it. I need to be able to have a file and read strings from the file and convert then to integers. As you may know schools are stupid and have no programs for me to use to edit .txt files so I will also need to format the file in python as well.

```
f = open("writ.txt","w")

f.write("3\n" "2") #writes original integers and I would like to use inputed intgers some other time

def a(): #My test if the lines are there. Usually comes up blank
    f = open("writ.txt","r")
print(f.readline(1))
print(f.readline(2))

def b():  #the problem is It comes up with a error when I run this
     f = open("writ.txt","r") 
     a = int(f.readline(1))
     b = int(f.readline(2))
     print(a)
     print(b)
```

When I run this and use the b() command I get this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I hope you know what's wrong because I'm stuck. Btw sorry if this isn't formatted correct I'm new here

Comment: Try to eval it instead of forcibly converting it to integer. eval(data)

Comment: What a terrible advice @TanveerAlam, there are very few cases when you should use eval.

Comment: I don't think you should use a word terrible to anybody's advice. Secondly eval always takes string as a parameter which we always get when we read data from file. So it might not be perfect but it gives an Idea of what the OP is missing here.

Comment: Doesn't `readline` take an optional argument to specify the number of bytes to be read? i.e. it doesn't specify which line to read. `f.readline()` would read the first line, calling it again would then read the next line. I suspect this is causing some confusion in what you're trying to convert to an int but I can't test it (e.g. you could be effectively trying to do `int("3\")` which won't work. Edit: cdarke's comment looks good too.

Comment: The probable reason why your readlines don't work is that you have not flushed the buffer to the file after the write.  Either use `f.flush()` after the write, or close the file.

Comment: Is the indentation here correct? Function `a` creates a file and then the function ends without doing anything?

Comment: @TanveerAlam: `f.write("3\n" "2")` won't cause an error. It's equivalent to writing `f.write("3\n2")`.

Comment: @elParaguayo I saw it incorrectly i thought it's comma between "3\n" and "2". That's why i removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer because it was a wrong assumption that `'3\n'` is an invalid int literal.

What's really happening here is that with `f.readline(1)` you are reading exactly 1 symbol from file. First you read `'3'` then you read `'\n'` and THIS is an invalid string literal. Use `'f.readline()'` instead.

Comment: This isn't the issue here - `int` removes leading/trailing whitespace, eg: `int('\t\t      3    \n\n\n')` is perfectly valid...

Comment: Ironically, `readline(1)` will return `3`, but `readline(2)` will read `\n2` which is still valid... the problem (which you've now removed from this answer) is really that the 3 bytes aren't physically in the file when it's re-opened (it's empty - it's neither been flushed/closed), hence, it's empty - causing an empty input - therefore the  `ValueError`... +1 for pointing out that the size parameter needn't be passed to `readline()` though

Comment: @JonClements this time I actually tested it before posting :) (without flush). And the file opened has data in it, but reads as i explained. readline(2) reads `'\n'` because it stops at the first occurrence of newline. That happens because file opened is written in the same variable as the write one, which closes it.

Comment: of course - one brain burp all - we'll call it evens? :p

Comment: @JonClements It might be contagious, evens :)

Comment: I'll just sneak in `a, b = map(int, f)` though :p